# Why does $GIT_DIR/info/exclude fail to negate a pattern defined by core.excludesfile?

Tags: git, version-control

I have the pattern `*.out` defined in my `core.excludesfile`. According to the [documentation](http://jk.gs/gitignore.html), patterns defined in `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` take precedence over `core.excludesfile`, so for one particular project that needs to track some `.out` files, I created `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` with just one pattern: `!*.out`.

Yet for some reason, `git status` still fails to report newly created `.out` files for that project. Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: FYI - the documention for that command is horrible.  I interpreted it the exact opposite of how you did, but it's all kinds of confusing.  Might as well wait to get an answer from git-devel or did into the source code.

Comment: @AndrewC yeah, see my comment on the answer below. It seems your interpretation of the docs is the correct one, even though it would be much more useful had it been the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check exactly which [`gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) rule is ignoring an element with [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v /path/to/my/file
```

In your case, check if the parent folder itself isn't already ignored (because in that case, any rule regarding files in that ignored folder wouldn't work anyway)

Comment: Thanks! As expected, it's being ignored by the `*.out` pattern in the `core.excludesfile` file. Its parent folder is not being ignored. So basically, the problem is that despite the wording in the docs indicating otherwise, the `core.excludesfile` is in fact overriding the `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`. That doesn't make much sense to me, because I'm much more likely to want to override global exclusions for a specific project, than override specific project settings with a global exclusion file (that really makes no sense).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a `.gitignore` file with the single pattern `!*.out` at the root of the project, and now `.out` files are no longer ignored for this project.

It's not an ideal solution because now all the other developers of the project who do not have `*.out` in their `core.excludesfile` will have an unnecessary pattern in their exclusion logic, but it does accomplish the intended result of unignoring .out files.